# Prove $f(z_0)I(\gamma;z_0)=\frac {g'(z_0)}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)}{g(z)-g(z_0)}dz. $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be analytic in a region A and let $g'(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in A$. Let g(z) be one to one and let $\gamma$ be a closed curve in A. Show that

$$ f(z_0)I(\gamma;z_0)=\frac {g'(z_0)}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)}{g(z)-g(z_0)}dz.  $$

What I can think of is to apply Cauchy Integral Theorem to $\frac {f(z)} {g'(z)}$ and obtain that

$$ f(z_0)I=\frac {g'(z_0)}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)} {g'(z)(z-z_0)}dz .$$

Then I cannot set up the relationship between that equality I found and the formula needed to prove. Any one could provide a help?

Many  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First note that in order for the statement to be true, $\gamma$ must 
satisfy $I(\gamma;z) = 0$ for all $z \notin A$. In particular, this is satisfied if
$A$ is *simply-connected*. (Otherwise a counterexample can easily
be constructed with $f(z) = 1/z, g(z) = z$ in a punctured disk around zero.)

For fixed $z_0 \in A$, the function
$$
 h(z) = \frac{f(z)}{g(z) - g(z_0)}
$$
is holomorphic in $A \setminus \{ z_0 \}$ (since $g$ is one-to-one),
and has (at most) a simple pole at $z_0$, with residue 
$$
 \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}
$$
The *Residue theorem* gives
$$
\frac {1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)}{g(z)-g(z_0)} \, dz
 = I(\gamma;z_0) \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)} \, .
$$

Alternatively, write
$$
 \frac{f(z)}{g(z) - g(z_0)} = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)} \frac{1}{z - z_0} + \varphi(z)
$$
where $\varphi$ is holomorphic in $A$, and apply the *Cauchy Integral theorem.*

Comment: Pls  Could you explain me why that ? $\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$

Comment: @davidhernandez: $h(z) = g(z) - g(z_0)$  has a simple zero at $z=z_0$, therefore the residue is $\frac{f(z_0)}{h'(z_0)} = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles.